# Can typescript guarantee that a callback is always called

Tags: typescript, express, callback

It is a common idiom in javascript to receive a callback which ends a function's execution. This can be either an express middleware where the `next` function must be called once (and exactly once!) for each code path eg:

```
function myMiddleware(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFn): void {
  if (someCondition) {
     next()
  }

  // this codepath never calls next, this will hang!
}
```

Or a consumer for a rabbitMQ message which must call either ack or nack. eg:

```
function messageConsumer(data: any, ack: () => void, nack: () => void) {
    if (someCondition) {
        console.log('did a thing');
        ack();
    } else if (otherCondition) {
        console.log('did other thing')
        ack();
    }

    // never called either ack nor nack.
}
```

Is there some typescript magic we can do so that tsc can help us ensure that we always call these functions (and also that whenever we call this functions we don't do anything else afterwards) ?

Comment: As far as I know, TS can't enforce that. At least not unless you do something like "this function **has** to return `SomeUniqueType` that's only returned by calling the callback". I took a quick glance as ESLint whether they might have a rule to enforce calling callbacks, but doesn't seem like it. Perhaps you could write an ESLint rule for that though, although personally I don't have any experience with that.

Comment: No, TypeScript can't enforce a call; [microsoft/TypeScript#21388](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21388) is the closest I can find to someone wanting something similar, and the response is mostly "what languages have such things" because it's not common.  I think if you want to make sure that a function always does something at the very end, then you really just want a `return`, and then you transform that function into a version that behaves as desired, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAVQ8W).  If that works I'll write up an answer; if not, please elaborate about why.

Comment: There is [an ESLint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) that can force you to *use* the `ack`/`nack`. But only a single usage is going to fullful it, if you have three code branches, call `ack` in one, `nack` in another and neither in the third, ESLint will not throw an error.

Comment: There is a nice feature in Rust https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html
It has nothing to do with typescript ))